# Cracks on both front and back differential - Normal?

Tags: audi, differential, awd, a4, quattro

AUDI A4 2012 2TFSI QUATTRO - I took my car into a service centre for a check and was told both differentials have got have cracks. Car is still on motor plan, took it into Audi to be replaced and was told it is normal. They cannot change it if is not broken. Can some one confirm if this is true?

Comment: Did you take it to an Audi dealer, or did you contact Audi themselves? The Audi Quattro is the *original* AWD rally car - I find it hard to believe that a cracked differential is normal.

Comment: @OP: StoP SHouTing!

Comment: Cracks on a 4 year old differential are normal? I haven't heard of cracks being normal on, well, anything...

Comment: You should probably get pictures of the diff's and include them in the question for someone to be able to answer with any level of relative confidence.